# PHP Newbie question; "notice: undefined property"

Tags: php, notice

I'm running the following code:

```
class Foo {  
    private $var = 0;

    function isVarSet () {
           return ($this->var != 0);
    }
}

...

foo = new Foo();
```

results in an "undefined property" notice: foo::$var on my PHP (ver. 5.3.5).

if I rewrite just the function isVarSet():

```
function isVarSet() {
    if (isset($this->var))
        return ($this->var != 0);
    return false;
}
```

the notice disappears.

This I do not understand. $var is set in both cases, why would it be an undefined property? Why do I need to use isset() to prevent this notice? Also, why does the notice refer to $var with the scope operator :: ? I'm not using a static class, I'm using an instance foo. $foo->isVarSet() should access a $var that is both defined and non-static.

I've been working on this for hours now and read all other answers on the undefined property notice, but this one I just don't get. Please enlighten me, StackOverFlow masters.

---

the code in my application:

```
<?php

class session {

    private $userId = 0;

    function __construct() {
    session_start();
    $this->setUserId();
    }

    public function isLoggedIn() {
    //if (isset($this->userId))
        return ($this->userId != 0);
    //return false;
    }

    function getUserId() {
    if (isset($this->userId))
        return $this->userId;
    else
        return false;
    }

    private function setUserId() {
    if (isset($_SESSION['userId'])) {
        $this->userId = $_SESSION['userId'];        
    } else 
        unset($this->userId);       
    }

    public function login($user) {
    if ($user != null) {        
        $_SESSION['userId'] = $user->id;
        $this->userId = $user->id;
    }
    }

     public function logout() {
    unset($_SESSION['userId']);
    unset($this->userId);   
    }    
}

$session = new Session();

?>
```

The call to the session class is made like so:

```
if ($session->isLoggedIn())
redirectToLocation("../public/index.php");
```

Comment: I've tried your code in same PHP release (5.3.5) on Windows server and it throws nothing (!?)

Comment: Please give us the complete code, you've added ... so there is more?

Comment: Just for snickers, try to declare the property as public or static and test again. No reproducy.

Comment: It does _not_ throw a notice, probably you removed the problem when cutting down the code to an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(after the whole edit).

What do you think this line does (in `setUserId`):

```
 unset($this->userId);
```

You might just want to set it to 0 as previous (which you recognize as not logged in:

```
 $this->userId = 0;
```

Or:

```
 $this->userId = null;
```

Take your pick.

Comment: Wow I can't believe I overlooked that. Thanks a lot for your time and answer. Should I remove this question from stackoverflow? Is that even possible? THanks again.

Comment: The idea is to leave the question be, so others may find it & possibly use the answer to their benefit (although here it's a somewhat localized answer the theory is still valid).

Comment: Or you can decide not to use unset and simple just make it 0 or null

Comment: @user658911: that was exactly what I said, but notice those are far from the same thing. A null-variable isn't the same as a non-existing variable.

Answer (score 0):

php 5.3.5/windows

```
<?php

  function eh($errno, $errstr) {
    echo "[$errno] $errstr";
    }

  set_error_handler('eh');

  class Foo {  
    private $var = 0;

    function isVarSet () {
      return ($this->var != 0);
      }

    public function testVar() {
      return var_export($this->isVarSet());
      }
    }

  $foo = new Foo();
  echo $foo->testVar();

?>
```

output is:

```
false
```

for `$var=1`, output is:

```
true
```

So it works perfectly here.

Answer (score -2):

I think it is because you didn't initialize your variable in your first example. You need to first initialize the var in a method which is called. Only then it is initialized.
Hope this helps you.

Comment: So it's not initialized by "private $foo = 0?" That is really confusing.

Comment: It is initialised by that, this answer is not the answer you're looking for.